# Label text not updating every frame

Tags: godot

So, I want to code something in Godot, but the `Label` text doesn't get updated every frame. Here's the script I attached:

```
extends Node2D

onready var SportVar = $Label
var counter = 0

func _ready():
    pass 

func _process(delta):
    SportVar.text = (str(counter))
```

Comment: What did you do to debug and isolate the cause of the issue?

Comment: It would be updating every frame. Except it would be updating to exactly the same thing. Edit: assuming you want the counter to increment by one every frame, then liggiorgio gave you the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your script is attached to a parent `Node2D` node, and **Label** is a `Label` child node.

Your script *is* updating the content of the Label. The reason you don't see updates is that the content itself isn't changing.

Adding the following line to the `_process()` function will update the text:

```
func _process(delta):
    counter += 1    # Increase value before updating text
    SportVar.text = (str(counter))
```

This is a continuous text update. If you want to update on value changed only, you can use [signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html) instead.